# sms notification for gmail email message

Tags: sms, gmail

I am trying to get SMS notification through my phone, whenever I will get email in my gmail account. Is it possible? If so please guide me step by step.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try ifttt.com.

One option for you could be : https://ifttt.com/recipes/11930

Comment: I registered here and I tried to activate the SMS channel but after providing my cell number also I am not getting any pin code. Also they have mentioned like "For international numbers, please include the leading “00” and country code. If you don’t receive the PIN, our provider may not work with your carrier yet." So what can I do now? is there any process?